# Access is Denied on GMAIL API access from Windows Azure (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, gmail-api

I'm facing a problem with GMAIL API from Windows Azure (ASP.NET MVC).

From Local or Console App everything works fine, when I move it to my cloud service I get an "Access is denied" error.

Obviously on the Google Cloud Platform console I have both "localhost" and "myurl" in order to make it work.

This is my code:

```
 UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(diskPath + "/Content/client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                    );
            }

            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            var resp = await service.HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=\"has:attachment\"");
```

I get the error on

```
await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                    );
```

I've the last package from NUGET for google API OAuth (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2).

I've seen online somebady referring to some access_type=offline parameter but I can't find any "completely working" example.

Why I get this huge difference between local and Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find out what was wrong with my solution!

Following this tutorial everything works fine:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

Summarizing:

Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)

Google APIs support OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications. In order to run the following code successfully, you must first add a redirect URI to your project in the Google API Console. Since you will use FlowMetadata and its default settings, set the redirect URI to your_site/AuthCallback/IndexAsync.

To find the redirect URIs for your OAuth 2.0 credentials, do the following:

Open the Credentials page in the API Console.
If you haven't done so already, create your OAuth 2.0 credentials by clicking Create credentials > OAuth client ID.
After you create your credentials, view or edit the redirect URLs by clicking the client ID (for a web application) in the OAuth 2.0 client IDs section.
After creating a new web application project in your IDE, add the right Google.Apis NuGet package for Drive, YouTube, or the other service you want to use. Then, add the Google.Apis.Auth.MVC package. The following code demonstrates an ASP.NET MVC application that queries a Google API service.

1) Add your own implementation of FlowMetadata.

```
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                },
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
            });

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
        // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
        // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
        // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
        // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
        var user = controller.Session["user"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = Guid.NewGuid();
            controller.Session["user"] = user;
        }
        return user.ToString();

    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }
}
```

FlowMetadata is an abstract class that contains your own logic for retrieving the user identifier and the IAuthorizationCodeFlow you are using.

In the above sample code a new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow is created with the right scopes, client secrets, and the data store. Consider adding your own implementation of IDataStore, for example you could write one that uses EntityFramework.

2) Implement your own controller that uses a Google API service. The following sample uses a DriveService:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (result.Credential != null)
        {
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
                });

            // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE..
            // SAMPLE CODE:
            var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
            ViewBag.Message = "FILE COUNT IS: " + list.Items.Count();
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

3 Implement your own callback controller. The implementation should be something like this:

```
 public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
{
    protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
    {
        get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
    }
}
```

This example is for Google Drive but if you want (as I did) to get it working for GMAIL API, you have just to switch between DriveService and GmailService

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/894433/you-may-receive-an-access-is-denied-error-message-when-you-try-to-debug-a-web-application-in-visual-studio-net-and-you-have-administrative-permissions), you may receive an `Access is denied` error message when you try to debug a Web application in Visual Studio .NET, and you have administrative permissions.

> The problem occurs when the following conditions are true:
>
> - You are logged on to your computer with administrative permissions.
> - You are debugging a Web application in Microsoft Visual Studio .NET.
> - The operating system that you are using is Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 2.
> - The Microsoft ASP.NET worker process account is not a member of the Administrators group.
>
> The problem occurs because the ASP.NET worker process does not have the Impersonate a client after authentication user right. If the worker process account does not have this right, the debugger cannot attach to the process. The worker process account is configured by using the processModel element in the Machine.config file.

You may also check the workaround given in this [post](http://www.sunilhaste.com/2011/04/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-error.html). Check if you have added below tag to the `web.config` file inside `system.webserver` tag.

```
<defaultDocument>    
   <files>    
       <add value="Pages/Home.aspx"/>    
   </files>    
</defaultDocument>
```